# mvn dependency:build-classpath not considering includeScope parameter

Tags: java, scala, maven

`mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=test`

doesn't show test jars that have been added to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However, `mvn -f pom.xml dependency:tree|grep tests` does show these test jars. Is this some kind of a bug in maven?

```
Using `mvn` from path: /usr/bin/mvn
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ java8-tests_2.10 ---
[INFO] org.apache.spark:java8-tests_2.10:pom:1.6.0-cdh5.11.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:tests:1.7.6-cdh5.11.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:test-jar:tests:1.6.0-cdh5.11.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.10:test-jar:tests:1.6.0-cdh5.11.0-SNAPSHOT:test
```

I am trying the above in a more complicated project mixing scala and java code. On a simpler sample project this does work.

Comment: I can't reproduce that on a sample project... so more information is needed here. Can you post a complete, but minimal, POM showing the behaviour?

Comment: It is also very frowned upon to cross post like this, without saying it.... http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/mvn-dependency-build-classpath-not-considering-includeScope-parameter-td5897291.html